# Set value from string to number

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using React-native and the `<Picker />` component.

The problem I am having, is that the `value='1'` is a string, but I would like it to return a number. I have seen ways to parse it, but I am unsure how to do this in react-native.

```
class TestPage extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myNumber:0
    }   
  }

  componentDidMount(){
  }

  render(){
    console.log('My value : ',this.state.myNumber);
    return (
      <View>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.myNumber}
          style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({myNumber: itemValue})}>
          <Picker.Item label="One" value="1" />//The value here 
          <Picker.Item label="Two" value="2" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `this.setState({myNumber: parseInt(itemValue, 10)})` or `this.setState({myNumber: Number(itemValue)})`?

Comment: Well that was logical, I didn't attempt to do that, which worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string to a number with the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function  or the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor.

```
this.setState({myNumber: parseInt(itemValue, 10)})
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the better way - [use unary "+"](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce):

```
this.setState({myNumber: +itemValue})
```

Comment: This is my preferred and most coincise way to manage string to number conversion. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState((itemValue)=>{myNumber: Number(itemValue)})}>
```